Как положить файл в загрузочный iso из терминала?
Вопрос в заголовке.
Есть загрузочный iso файл и есть просто файл, который нужно запихнуть в этот самый iso (в iso есть папка).
Пробовал ручками через gui так ложить. Замаялся постоянно его ручками ложить заново.
xorriso просто делает образ не загрузочным(qemu bios не находит загрузочных устройств):
xorriso -indev bootable.iso -outdev bootable.iso add myfile

